# How to find Longitude and Latitude from an Address Reading from an Excel doc (Python)?

Tags: python, geocoding, jupyter-lab

**I am trying to read an excel doc that contains addresses and then find the corresponding longitude and latitudes. I am running into an error and not sure how to continue. Getting error: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'". Any help would be appreciated! Here is the code:**

```
import pandas as pd

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myApp")

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\scott.correia\Desktop\SoS_Test.xlsx') 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Location'])

df2[['location_lat', 'location_long']] = df2['Location'].apply(
    geolocator.geocode).apply (lambda x: pd.Series(
        [x.latitude, x.longitude], index = ['location_lat', 'location_long']))

print(df2)
```

[HERE IS WHAT EXCEL SHEET LOOKS LIKE I AM READING]    [image: 1]

**When I run it with inputting a manual address it works seen here:**

```
import pandas as pd

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myApp")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Location':
            ['188 Glezen Lane Wayland MA 01778']})

df2[['location_lat', 'location_long']] = df2['Location'].apply(
    geolocator.geocode).apply (lambda x: pd.Series(
        [x.latitude, x.longitude], index = ['location_lat', 'location_long']))

print(df2)
```

**OUTPUT:**

Location  location_lat  location_long

0  188 Glezen Lane Wayland MA 01778     42.386672     -71.345426

Comment: I always found [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/geocoding.html) easy to use for stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are over-complicating things a little... This is a simple enough task - take a list of addresses and run it through a function. Something like this should do it:

```
addresses = pd.read_excel (data_path)["Location"]
coords = zip(*map(lambda addr: (addr.latitude, addr.longitude),
             addresses))

data = pd.DataFrame({"Location" : addresses, 
     "Latitude" : coords[0],
     "Longitude" : coords[1]})
```

Comment: I am trying to get this method to work but running into another error. I am not as familiar with the map() function but I am getting the message "argument 2 to map() must support iteration"

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the arguments should be in reverse order.